# How can keep the key when the value of that key is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What im trying to do is to not change the key of an item inside an array when the value is changed.
So basically the user can update, delete or add a new language.
To notice it In my code, I will have to add a key "added" (which means is a language added by the user when he created the account.)
When the user adds a new language the array will look like this:

```
language:
[
  {
     added: "English"
  },

  "Italian" //the new language add by user when edit
]
```

parent.js

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get('api').then((response) => {
              response.data.user.map((user) => {setLanguage([...language,{added:user.language)}))
}, [])
```

child.js

```
export default function child({language, setLanguage}) {
    const handleAddClick = () => {
    setLanguage([...language, ""]);
  };

  const handleItemChanged = (event, index) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const list = [...language];
    console.log("list: ", list);

    list[index] = value;

    setLanguage(list);
  };
}
```

So the problem is when the user updates the language that has the key `added`, the key will disappear, and the array will look like this:

```
language: 
[
   "Englishhh", //updated
   "Italian"
]
```

So I wanted the result like this:

```
language
[
  {
    added: "Englishhh" //updated
  },
  "Italian"
]
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this way before setting the language in handleItemChanged?

```
if(typeof list[index] !== 'string'){
 list[index].added ? list[index].added = value : list[index].language = value;
}else{
 list[index] = value;
}
```

Comment: Your logic works, thank you.  What if list[index] I added to another key name in the same array, what the code would be?

Comment: Example: ```[{added:"English"}, {language: "Italian"}]

Comment: It should still work as your modifications are based on index. At a time you would be updating only one index right? And I see that the key is changed to language for the second one. Is that expected? In that case you need to check whether that index has added or language property and then update it accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the above code. See if it helps.